# What is preventing Edge from interpolating a frames var data?

Tags: javascript, microsoft-edge, frames

I am researching why our website is not responding on Edge. We have two elements on the page that are using frames. One is a text field and the other is a dropdown. The code listens and responds once the dropdown has been populated. However, when running it on Edge & Firefox the application remains idle and does not respond. Basically, the child frame is not passing the var data to the parent.

I have cleared my cache, the code does work on IE. I have also researched the Lazy Frame Loading/Load on Demand feature in Chromium to see if that is presenting a bug, but I could not find anything.

Has anyone ran into this issue?

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    parent.frames.menu.mainform.THIS_ID.value="";
    parent.frames.menu.mainform.MORE_TYPE.value="";
    parent.frames.menu.mainform.REFRESH.value=0;
    parent.frames.menu.mainform.SOME_OTHER_VAR.value=$write_perm;
    parent.frames.menu.eval('clickImage("home")');
    parent.frames.menu.mainform.THAT_ID.value=""; 
</script>

<script type='text/javascript' language='javascript'>

function resetAllInputs () {
    document.ADM_Form.THAT_ID.value = "";
    document.ADM_Form.THIS_ID.value = "";
    document.ADM_Form.IP.value="";
    document.ADM_Form.WHAT_TYPE.value="";
    document.ADM_Form.MORE_TYPE.value="";
    parent.frames.menu.mainform.SOME_ID.value = "";
    parent.frames.menu.mainform.OTHER_ID.value = "";
    parent.frames.menu.mainform.SOME_TYPE.value="";
    parent.frames.menu.mainform.REFRESH.value=document.SOME_Form.REFRESH.value;
    
}
```

Comment: Does the website work in Chrome? You can open F12 devtools to check if there's any error in console. Besides, with the code you provide, I can't reproduce the issue. Please provide [a minimal code snippet](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) which can **reproduce** the issue, including related html and javascript codes.

Comment: Here is the output from console. The '-->' begins each error.
-->home.cgi:3 
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'eval')
at onload (home.cgi:3:109)
-->:8002/favicon.ico:1 
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
-->home.cgi:67         
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'mainform')
 at resetAllInputs (home.cgi:67:36)
 at onClickSub (home.cgi:91:17)
 at HTMLSelectElement.onchange (home.cgi:27:83)
resetAllInputs @ home.cgi:67
onClickSub @ home.cgi:91
onchange @ home.cgi:27

Comment: Do you load the code through file protocol or on a server? JavaScript frame communication doesn't work when on the local file system. How do you define `frames`, `menu`, `mainform`? I use [Window.frames](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/frames) to get `var` data in iframe and it works in all browsers. Please provide a code snippet which can run and reproduce the issue, so that I can have a test and see how to help.